# mapping (routing) tool

Tags: appexchange

Does anyone have any recommendations on a mapping tool that would provide the following functionality?

I need to optimize driving routes for sales reps based on accounts they are visiting in a specific area.  Basically, so they don't go to one account and then drive across town to visit another account, and then back the other direction all the way across town, etc.

Also, I would want the app to be mobile capable so that the sales rep, when they visit the account can simply click on the marker on their phone and it opens salesforce to that account so they can quickly fill in the account visit details and move on to the next account.

Has anyone worked with any routing and mapping tools that easily accomplish these tasks?

Any recommendations are appreciated.
Thanks.

Comment: Have you checked out the App Exchange?

Comment: The one that immediately comes to mind is this one...http://www.arrowpointe.com/products/geopointe/